# Place the mean of the column equal to 100 and transform other values in the column proportionally (Pandas Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, standardized

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
City  Variable1 
c1    1234      
c2    2222      
c3    1111      
c4    2224
```

I would like to apply a form of standardization where:

- the mean of the column is placed equal to 100.
- the values are transformed proportionally to the mean.

For instance, the mean of the column Variable1 is 1697.75. If I place this mean equal to 100 and I make proportions, I have this desired output:

```
City | Variable1  
_________________
c1   | 72,68     
c2   | 130,88    
c3   | 65,44     
c4   | 131
```

How can i do it in Python? I can install any library.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the mean of the column and simply divide each row by that:

```
df1[" Variable1 "] = df1[" Variable1 "] / df1[' Variable1 '].mean() * 100
```

Output:

```
   City Variable1
0   c1  72.684435
1   c2  130.879105
2   c3  65.439552
3   c4  130.996908
```